# How to keep the image in place when screen size changes? HMTL/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, position

I'm trying to make a html header with a title and an image on the right side of the title. But when the screen size alters the image moves over sliding over the title. How do a make it stay in its place? I've tried all I can think of with no luck. Best that I have come up with is when the image is under the title. Then it keeps its place. But I'd rather have it on the side.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <header>
        <h1>Title text</h1>
        <p>some text</p>
        <div class="picture">
          <img src="assets/images/xxxx.png">
        </div>
      </header>
some code ....
</body>
```

and the header part in style.css:

```
header { padding: 25px 20px 40px 20px; margin: 0; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center; background: #15253e; box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); z-index: 99; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; min-height: 76px; }
header h1 { font: 42px/50px 'Copse', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #f3f3f3; text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #235796; margin: 0px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; }
header p { color: #f3f3f3; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 1px 0; font-size: 20px; margin: 10px; }
header img { width: 60px; height: 100px; position: fixed; right: 900px; top: 15px; text-align: right; }
header .picture { display: block; }
```

I would have added a picture but I haven't got the rights to do so. So here is a page [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857495/html-header-with-image-and-text-align-text-to-bottom/24857562) that might give an undestanding of what I'm trying to do. There is a picture of a header and an arrowimage. My goal is to get the image on the right side of the header text. And keep it there if the screen size alters.

Comment: Please provide more details and [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what more details? There is the header part and the img?

Comment: For example what is your desired result and what do you get, provide a working example. Nobody knows what do you want so if you want some help you have to provide more deails. If you have some doubt about how to ask  read [ask]

Comment: css `boxäshadow` do not exist. And you did not close your `img` element (missing `>`)

Comment: I want the image in the header on the right side of the header title. Now the image floats over the title when the screen size changes. I don't know how to more clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a property set for your header `text-align: center;` it aligns your image to center because it's inline element. You have many options to change it:

- set `text-align: right;`
- put your image into a block element like `<div>`
- change property of your image to block or flex... ex: `display: block;` and change position of your div with `float:right`
- other stuff

Look examples [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_templates.asp)

Use Sandbox like [Codepen](https://codepen.io)

Answer (score 0):

I really hope that's it now:

I put the whole content in a `flexbox`, so it's easy to align.
You can modify the header's `justify-content` or `align-items` to change the layout a bit.

Inside of `#title` the `text-align` can also be changed to `center` or `left` for example.

I know in code preview it looks quite big, but in fullscreen it works. You can change the `height` in the `header` to eliminate that problem.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 30vh;
}

#title {
  text-align: right;
}

header h1 {
  font: 42px/50px 'Copse', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #235796;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

header p {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 1px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

header img {
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="title">
      <h1>Title text</h1>
      <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png">
  </header>
  <div>
    spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
    <br> spacefiller
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tried that. Stills moves to the left if screen size gets smaller. I edited the question once more. Coudn't give a picture (no rights for that) but added a link were is a picture that resembles what I'm trying to do. Except that the arrowimage is on the left and I want the image on the right side.

Comment: what should happen to the header if the side getts scrolled down? should it stay on top of the screen?

Comment: The header stays in its place.

Comment: look i changed it so you can see the scroll effect